# How to remove 3D border on JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` with a `JScrollPane` that makes sure there's a scroll bar in case it becomes too large. It all works perfectly fine, and here's a screenshot of it:

[image: Screenshot]

You can't see the scrollbar right now because it's not necessary, but that's not the problem. The problem is around the `JTable` and lower (revealing the size of the `JScrollPane`), you can see a border that kind of makes it look 3D with a shadow and such. I wish to remove this. I can't seem to find any property that disables this and both the `JTable` and `JScrollPane` have no border of any kind (no default either). Any ideas on how to remove this 3D border?

Comment: Is `setBorder` not working for you?

Comment: @JoeC I already mentioned how no border is set. The code already in place is `table.setBorder(null);` which puts no (not even the default) border.

Comment: Have you tried setting an `EmptyBorder` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this 3D border was actually generated by the Default look and feel. By changing this, I was able to remove the border.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say since you show no code, but do both getBorder() and getViewportBorder() return null when called on the **JScrollPane** (not the JTable).

Which LnF (look and feel) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
   jScrollPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
   jTable.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

Use your own variable names relevant to "jScrollPane" and "jTable". It is better to use Windows Look and Feel to have a good look.

Answer (score 0):

In LookAndFeel initialization just set empty border:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("ScrollPane.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Table.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

It will affect all *ScrollPane objects* around your applicatin, if you wanto t change just single one use this code:

```
jScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
jTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

In case you want to save top line border for header use *MatteBorder*:

```
BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0,Color.LIGHT_GRAY))//1 is top line, rest is empty
```